# Trying to get a JFormattedtextfield to change... not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jformattedtextfield

I'm trying to set whatever is entered into "titleField" to appear in "artistField" by passing it through the string variable title

I type text into titleField, press enter, and nothing appears in artistField

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
titleField.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e){

        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == titleField) {
            title = (String)titleField.getValue();
        }
    }
});
artistField = new JFormattedTextField();
artistField.setText(title);
```

Comment: too lazy to read through all your comments, so just ignore if already discussed :-) Assuming titleField is a JFormattedTextField and its Formatter commits on enter, your PropertyChangeListener will be called. Just: it will not effect anything visible, as it updates the a _String_ field, not a _property_ (text/value) of artistField - no way the artistField can be aware of a change to a comletely unrelated member :-)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need to use an `JFormattedTextField` or can you use a `JTextField` with a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) as camickr suggest? What `Formatter` are you using?

It is only the code in the `propertyChange()` method that is executed when the propery is changed. So you have to update `artistField` from that method. You should also update `JFormattedTectFields` using `setValue()` instead of `setText()` since `setText()` only updates the text and not the actual content.

Try with this PropertyChangeListener:

```
titleField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e){

        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == titleField) {
            String title = (String)titleField.getValue();
            artistField.setValue(title);
        }
    }
});
```

Your `JFormattedTextField` needs a `Formatter` that can handle `String`. Here is a dumb formatter that just returns the same String (A `JTextField` and a `DocumentListener` is a better choice if you don't need a `Formatter`):

```
class StringFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {

    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
        return (String)value;
    }

}
```

You use it when you initilise the `JFormattedTextField` like:

```
JFormattedTextField titleField = new JFormattedTextField(new StringFormatter());
```

Comment: hmmm ok, but is there a way to "send the variable" so to speak, so that it can be used in other classes?

Comment: @user1091665: You can create a class that implements `PropertyChangeListener` and pass the fields in a Constructor.

Comment: I get no errors, it just doesn't change the other text field. It's a GUI where I'm trying to input text into the fields and then display them in another method

I change the text in the titleField, hit enter, and nothing happens in artistField it just stays blank

Comment: oh, I just switched it and still nothing, I think it might be that I'm trying to cast to String but it's not working properply?

Comment: @camickr: A propertyChangeListener is used for the **value** in a `JFormattedTextField`. See "Setting and Getting the Field's Value" in [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: -1, sorry, I missed that the question was for a JFormattedTextField. Normally a DocumentListener is used to listen for changes to the text field. I can't remove the downvote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: Yes, that link should have been posted as the original answer. Then the poster could have read the tutorial and copied the code from the example. I never understand why people try to post there own solution when the tutorial has a working solution with an explanation. Not only would the tutorial link solve this problem, it will be a reference for future questions.

Comment: @Axschech: You are right, my code doesn't work. Probably because it's a string. Can you use an `JTextField` with a `DocumentListener`  instead?

Comment: Because I'm doing a project and don't want to to cheat? lol edit: also I'm doing almost exactly what the tutorial does i dont know what im missing, the tutorial doesnt use a documentlistener

Comment: @Axschech: Have you seen my update? You can use a PropertyChangeListener but you need a Formatter similar to my `StringFormatter`. That code works.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling commitEdit before getValue maybe. Check out the Java Doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#getValue%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

> I type text into titleField, press enter, and nothing appears in artistField

If your requirement is to do some processing when `Enter` is pressed, then you should be using an ActionListener. An ActionListion can be added to a JFormattedTextField or a JTextField. Then in the ActionLIstener code you can get the text and reset your other variable.